# Javafx 2.0 ChoiceboxPop UP Position Changes Weirdly

Tags: javafx-2

I have a problem with choiceBox in my project.
When i make a selection on choicebox, pop up menu appereance on different areas for all time.
I mean when i make a selection, pop up menu position changes and not even close choicebox.
I am really confused. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your javafx version, OS and java version?

Comment: JavaFx 2.0.1  windows XP

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Can you provide screenshot and code you use? Also you can try newer  build: 2.0.3 or 2.1dev -- you may encounter an issue which is already fixed.

Comment: Thanks. i will try:) I hope its fixed :) take care and thans again...

Comment: Hi again. İ guess i found whats the reason of this problem. I am using JavaFX on Java swing frame. i added some JFXPanel on JFrame and components on the JFXPanl dont know their location because of JFXPanel can not get location info from Swing. İ mean when i added a JFXPanel into middle of screen, JFXPanels doesnt know its location and think its at 0,0 point. When i give a parametre of tis location to Scenes it works but its not efficient.

Comment: By the way, sorry about my english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, you are using embedded JavaFX. It seems you've encountered issue http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-15970 (Popups aren't drawn in the right place in applet mode if the browser window is moved). It's targeted for upcoming 2.1 release so you may just wait till it.